# python: how to import a module

Tags: python, import

I'm a newbie in using Python.
What I need is simple: import a module dynamically.

Here is my little test:

```
#module
class Test:
    def func(self, id, name):
        print("Your ID: " + str(id) + ". Your name: " + name)
        return
```

I put this class in a file named `my_module.py` and the path of the file is: `c:\doc\my_module.py`.

Now I create a new python project to import the file above.

Here is what I do:

```
import sys
module = sys.path.append(r'c:\doc\my_module.py')
myClass = module.__class__
print(myClass)
```

However, I got this result:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Why can't I get `Test`?

Is it because the way to import a module is wrong or because I need to do some config to import a module?

Comment: `sys.path ` is a list of directories, not files. Do you not want to `append(r'c:\doc\')`? Also appending it to path doesn't load the module, it just adds an extra path in which `import` should look for modules.

Comment: @Stej   if I do this, how to locate the py file that I want to import?

Comment: See the answers posted below by user2750362 and Nhor -- adding the directory your .py file to sys.path should be enough to locate the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Here's how you should import your module with `sys.path.append`:

```
import sys                    # import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\doc\')   # add your module path to ``sys.path``
import my_module              # now import your module using filename without .py extension
myClass = my_module.Test      # this is how you use the ``Test`` class form your module
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: module 'my_module' has no attribute 'Test'

Comment: are you sure the `Test` class is present in `my_module`?

Comment: It seems that because I have another file with the same file name. Anyway, this error is solved. But now I have a new error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: python is indent-sensible language, so you *have* to have proper intendations in your file. this sometimes also happens when you mix spaces with tabs

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\doc\')  # make sure python find your module

import my_module    # import your module 

t = my_module.Test() # Initialize the Test class
t.func(1, 'test')  # call the method
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to import a module is through the import command. You can specify the path with sys as a directory. You also need to instantiate the class within the module (through the my_module.Test()). See the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\doc\\')
import my_module

myObj = my_module.Test()
myClass = myObj.__class__
print(myClass)
```